# Trouble cutting cells with data and moving to different sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble with a macro I am trying to create.

I want to look up whether a cell has a particular month in it, and if so, cut a range from that cells row to another sheet.

Here is the code I've got so far:

```
Sub MoveToMonth()
  Dim n As Long
  Dim nLastRow As Long
  Dim nFirstRow As Long
  Dim lastRow As Integer
  Dim i As Long: i = 1
  Dim CellMonth As String

  ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  With Sheets("DATA_IMPORT")
    nFirstRow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    nLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    n = nLastRow

    With .Cells(n, "B")
      For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        CellMonth = Format(.Value, "mmmm")
        If CellMonth = "November" Then
          .Cells(n, "B").Cut Worksheets("November").Cells(i, "T")
          i = i + 1
        End If
      Next
    End With

  End With

End Sub
```

This code executes without any errors, but nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Also once I get this code working, I will actually be aiming to check the value of B, but cut A:E.

I will also be checking against every month, however I am just using November in this example to get the code working as the data set I am testing with has values from November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the `For` loop order a little mixed-up, it needs to be outside the `With .Cells(n, "B")`. You can get rid of the `With .Cells(n, "B")` entirely.

See section of code below:

```
For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
    CellMonth = Format(.Cells(n, "B").Value, "mmmm")
    If CellMonth = "November" Then
        .Cells(n, "B").Cut Worksheets("November").Cells(i, "T")
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: Of course.. That works perfectly, thanks Shai.

I've cleaned it up a little to work for all months. The only problem I am trying to solve is, when it runs this bit:


`.Range("A" & n & ":E" & n).Cut Worksheets(CellMonth).Cells(i, "T")`
`i = i + 1`


The i count continues for the whole list, meaning it isn't pasting in the first empty cell of T in the relevant sheet.
I've thought I could have a seperate counter for each month, but that could get messy and would mean I would have to have ifelse statements for every month rather than the one statement which works for all. Any ideas?

Comment: @dweeman just look for the next empty cell for that worksheet, no need to use a counte